# I want to parse a cell in a spreadsheet and replace certain letters with a multiplier

Tags: worksheet-function, google-sheets

Someone submitted a neat [price list of medieval goods](http://medieval.ucdavis.edu/120D/Money.html) to Hacker News today, and the list is a little hard to read because the prices are in their typical values (e.g. "4s" for 4 shillings, or "13s 4d" for "13 shillings 4 pence"). I had a thought to try to normalize the table in to pence (or shillings or even try to compare it to modern dollars) but I am having trouble figuring out how to parse a cell based on another table of cells.

So I've got a table of denominations with their symbols, and how much that denomination is worth in pence:

[image: Currency values]

And then I have a table of prices:

[image: Price list]

It seems that if I could replace or treat all the symbols in the price list as variables, and have Sheets multiply numbers that are next to each other (and then treat spaces as "+") that I could get the pence value of each item (after manually cleaning up data where spacing/numbering is inconsistent). But I have no idea how to do something like that, or how to do a 'look up' in the denomination table.

Answer (score 1):

This should work in most cases, but you would need to split on `-` where relevant and handle the ends of the range separately (then stitch back together?):

[image: WA111744 example]

Replace is found under Edit > Find and replace... . For a result in (old) pence.

However I can't see you doing this *often* so would expect some manual 'adjustment' to be acceptable.